# Occurrence of weird artifacts

Tags: video, graphics-card, visual-artifacts

I've noticed that some videos and some specific resolutions like >720p are displayed in the following manner:

[image: Artifact]

I tried updating all drivers but the issue still persists. It started happening very recently and I am concerned that it might be a hardware related issue. What do you guys think?

Edit:

Specification:

```
ASUS ROG Strix G G531GV
RTX 2060
Windows 10
```

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: The times that I've seen this kind of thing happen, the computer crashed (apparently due to unrelated bluetooth drivers for a dongle) or the given resolution was unsupported (under Linux, if I recall correctly). It might be helpful to be more specific about the system itself (OS, card, etc.) and what specific steps cause this issue.

Comment: I've added a specification to the original post. Nothing unusual has to be done to get such a result. Open a specific video that caused a problem, whether it be youtube or different platform.

Comment: Can you try a different monitor? This will help determine whether Display or graphics unit on the main computer board.

Comment: Is that a photo or a screenshot? The regularity of the border tells me it's a screenshot… in which case that & the fact the 'fullscreen/PiP' icon renders just fine tells me it's entirely a software issue, not hardware.

Comment: Yes, that's a screenshot. As I mentioned, sometimes I see that video works perfectly fine with 480p but not with 720p.

Comment: Moreover, I see random 'refreshes' of rendered display sometimes. I've heard that it might be related to issues with a driver, but I've already tried updating it.

Comment: Try going back a driver or three, see if it's a specific build. [Clean install or it won't overwrite correctly]

Comment: The latest version of Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 seems to be an issue here. After rolling back to older version I see no issues in all places they occurred. Thank you for all suggestions.